# Number of solutions to $x^{k}\equiv 1\pmod {p}$

Tags: number-theory

Let $p$ be a prime. We learned that the number of solutions to $x^k\equiv 1\pmod{p}$ is $\gcd(k, p-1)$ and I know how to prove it in case $k$ divides $p-1$.

But how do I prove it in the other case?

Comment: Is $p$ considered to be a prime?

Comment: Note that $x^{jk}=(x^k)^j$

Comment: @Arthur yes, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $d=\gcd(k,p-1)$ and write $d=ku+(p-1)v$.

Then $x^d \equiv (x^k)^u (x^{p-1})^v \equiv (x^k)^u$. This proves that $x^k\equiv 1$ implies $x^d \equiv 1$.

On the other hand, $x^d\equiv 1$ implies $x^k \equiv 1$ simply because $d$ divides $k$.

Thus, the set of solutions of $x^k \equiv 1$ is the same as the set of solutions of $x^d\equiv 1$, and the problem has been reduced to the case when $k$ divides $p-1$.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Discrete Logarithm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiscreteLogarithm.html), $k\cdot $ind$(x)\equiv0\pmod{p-1}$

Now use  [Linear Congruence Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LinearCongruenceEquation.html)